# How to automatically retry github action jobs on failure?

Tags: github

I am building github action pipelines, I want to add an auto retry to my jobs similar to how [the retry keyword works in gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#retry), where on failure the full step will be run again. Is there anything in github actions that allows this?

Here is an example job I am using:

```
jobs:
  env-check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: myimage
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: env-check
        run: |
          echo "foobar"
```

Answer (score 24):

There does not seem to be a retry in GitHub Action syntax, which is why you find complementary GitHub Actions like:

- [Retry Step](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/retry-step): Retries an Action step on failure or timeout. This is currently intended to replace the run step for moody commands.
- [Retry Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/retry-action): Retries an Github Action step or command on failure.

Example:

```yaml
uses: nick-fields/retry@v2
with:
  timeout_minutes: 10
  max_attempts: 3
  command: npm run some-typically-slow-script
```

---

> These do not work with other `uses` directives though, right?
> So they only work if you are running explicit commands, with no dependencies?

Correct. Retry actions like `nick-fields/retry` work by re-running a command that you specify, so it will not work directly with other `uses` directives. This means it is most applicable when you are running explicit shell commands.

However, you can potentially workaround this limitation if the action you are using can be run via a shell command. Many actions are essentially just scripts that you can execute from the command line, so if the action you are using fits this description, you can use the retry action to rerun that command.

For example, if you are using an action like `actions/checkout@v2` and it has a command line interface, you could do something like this:

```yaml
uses: nick-fields/retry@v2
with:
  timeout_minutes: 10
  max_attempts: 3
  command: |
    git clone https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}.git
    cd {repo}
```

Keep in mind that this is just a workaround and might not be applicable for every action.
Also, if the action you are using does not have a command line interface, or if it performs complex tasks that are not easily replicable with shell commands, this workaround will not be applicable.

Finally, do note that the retry action would retry the *entire* command, so if you have multiple commands and only want to retry a specific one, you would need to use multiple instances of the retry action.

---

[a p](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002371/c) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574593/how-to-automatically-retry-github-action-jobs-on-failure/71583518?noredirect=1#comment134737399_71583518):

Actually, after a few hours of looking, this [retry action `Wandalen/wretry.action`](https://github.com/Wandalen/wretry.action) DOES seem to do the right thing: in both command and sub-action cases.

Note the official documentation remains "[Re-running workflows and jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/re-running-workflows-and-jobs)".

Comment: Great!
This executes on the same runner though, right? Would be nice if we could retry on another available runner. In my setup, the runners can often be the issue.

Comment: These don't work with other `uses` directives though, right? So they only work if you're running explicit commands, with no dependencies.

Comment: @ap I believe so, yes. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Actually, after a few hours of looking, this retry action DOES seem to do the right thing: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/retry-action in both command and sub-action cases.

Comment: @ap So it does work directly with other uses directives? That would be great!

Comment: @VonC it does, yes

Answer (score 7):

You can rerun failed jobs in the current workflow with additional job. It will be executed after all other jobs, if any of them fail.

```
rerun-failed-jobs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [ job1, job2]
    if: failure()
    steps:
      - name: Rerun failed jobs in the current workflow
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        run: gh run rerun ${{ github.run_id }} --failed
```

Comment: I really wanted this solution to work since it would also work for jobs that are already using another action and cannot be called directly...but I'm getting a few errors that are preventing me from using it. The main one I can't get past is `run 7670584017 cannot be rerun; its workflow file may be broken`. Couldn't be the workflow file though since its the same file that this job is running from, otherwise it wouldn't run at all. @mikamika are you using this in a current workflow and its working?

Comment: @MikeHarrison did you ever get this to work? I'm receiving the same "may be broken" error