# How to rerun GitHub pipeline when it faces a faliure

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, ansible, github-actions

i am not able to find a solution to the problem i am facing. When i run ansible playbook in GitHub, sometime we face failures but when we rerun the pipeline, it all completes without issue. I would like to have a rerun of pipeline step in my workflow so that if there is a failure, it reruns the pipeline, here is my workflow file

```
  name: ansible

  on:
    pull_request:
      branches:
       - main
    push:
      branches:
       - main
    workflow_dispatch:

 jobs:
   ansible:
     runs-on: my-runner
     continue-on-error: true

     env:
       AWS_REGION: eu-west-1
       AWS_PROFILE: my-profile
       PACKER_LOG: '1'
       ANSIBLE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.ansible_password }}

     steps:
       - name: Checkout code
         uses: actions/checkout@v2

       - name: Setup AWS configuration
         run: scripts/actions-setup-aws-config

       - name: Install Python
         uses: actions/setup-python@v3
         with:
           python-version: '3.8'

       - name: Install Ansible
         run: pip install ansible

       - name: Install pywinrm
         run: pip install "pywinrm>=0.2.2"

       - name: Create Ansible Inventory File
         run: |
      echo "[windows]" > inventory.ini
      ips=("ips of windows servers")
      for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
        echo "$ip ansible_user=ansible ansible_password=$ANSIBLE_PASSWORD ansible_connection=winrm ansible_port=5985 ansible_winrm_scheme=http" >> inventory.ini
      done

  - name: Run Ansible Playbook
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch'
    run: |
      ansible-playbook playbooks/configure.yaml -i inventory.ini
    continue-on-error: true
    env:
      ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK: default
      ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING: "False"
      ANSIBLE_PIPELINING: "True"

  - name: Run Ansible Playbook (Dry Run)
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
    run: |
      ansible-playbook --check playbooks/configure.yaml -i inventory.ini
    continue-on-error: true
    env:
      ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK: default
      ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING: "False"
      ANSIBLE_PIPELINING: "True"
```

Comment: The whole pipeline (all the jobs) or just one step? How about this:  [How to automatically retry github action jobs on failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574593/how-to-automatically-retry-github-action-jobs-on-failure)

Comment: i wanted to run whole pipeline again